# Relational Algebra Queries - How to Approach Problems?

Tags: relational-theory

I have the following schema:

`employee(sin, emp_name, emp_address, salary, supervisor_sin, dept#)`

`works_on(emp_sin, project_number, hours)`

The question is:

`Assume that no employee works on more than 2 projects. For those employees
working on two projects, give the employee name and the two project numbers.
Each employee name should appear once only`

My solution so far:

`R1 = works_on [theta-join]emp_sin=d.emp_sin [Rename]d(works_on)` - gets tuples in the form "emp_sin | project_number | d.project_number | hours | d.hours"?

`Result = [Projection]emp_name,project_number,d.project_number(employee [theta-join]sin=emp_sin R1)` - gets all names, and 2 project numbers in the form "emp_name | project_number | d.project_number"?

Is this correct thinking? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're on the right track, but I'm not seeing a provision for restricting the results to employees who are actually working on two projects and the rename notation is confusing to me.  You'll probably want to leverage a theta-join on a self join to accomplish this.

To start out, I would rename the relevant attributes in the work table in preparation for a self-join:

> ρ<sub>sin/emp_sin,project_number1/project_number</sub> works_on

Then project just those attributes for simplicity's sake:

> π<sub>sin,project_number1</sub> ( ρ<sub>sin/emp_sin,project_number1/project_number</sub> works_on )

For visualization purposes, the equivalent SQL here would be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT  emp_sin 
            AS sin,
        project_number
            AS project_number1
FROM    works_on;
```

I'd then prepare for the self join by creating another relationship, renaming the `project_number` differently:

> π<sub>sin,project_number2</sub> ( ρ<sub>sin/emp_sin,project_number2/project_number</sub> works_on )

At this point, a theta-join can be applied, exploiting the maximum of 2 carnality as defined in the assumption.  This theta-join creates a relationship with both `project_numbers` by `emp_sin`:

> ( π<sub>sin,project_number1</sub> ( ρ<sub>sin/emp_sin,project_number1/project_number</sub> works_on ) ) ⋈<sub>sin, project_number1 < project_number2</sub> ( π<sub>sin,project_number2</sub> ( ρ<sub>sin/emp_sin,project_number2/project_number</sub> works_on ) )

In effect, this is similar to SQL as follows:

```
SELECT  *
FROM (  SELECT  emp_sin 
                    AS sin,
                project_number
                    AS project_number1
        FROM    works_on ) AS w1
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  emp_sin 
                    AS sin,
                project_number
                    AS project_number2
        FROM    works_on ) AS w2 
    ON  w1.sin = w2.sin
    AND w1.project_number1 < w2.project_number2;
```

The little exploit in the requirements here lets us do a natural join and a final projection to finish up ( since I've already renamed the `emp_sin` attribute to `sin` ):

> π<sub>emp_name, project_number1, project_number2</sub> ( employee ⋈ ( π<sub>sin,project_number1</sub> ( ρ<sub>sin/emp_sin,project_number1/project_number</sub> works_on ) ) ⋈<sub>sin, project_number1 < project_number2</sub> ( π<sub>sin,project_number2</sub> ( ρ<sub>sin/emp_sin,project_number2/project_number</sub> works_on ) ) )

Again, as visual proof, this is approximately the equivalent of the following SQL, shown in action in [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d53f6/1):

```
SELECT  e.emp_name, w1.project_number1, w2.project_number2
FROM    dbo.employee e
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  emp_sin 
                    AS sin,
                project_number
                    AS project_number1
        FROM    dbo.works_on ) AS w1
    ON  e.sin = w1.sin
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  emp_sin 
                    AS sin,
                project_number
                    AS project_number2
        FROM    dbo.works_on ) AS w2 
    ON  w1.sin = w2.sin
    AND w1.project_number1 < w2.project_number2;
```